# How do I stop a horizontal list from breaking within a list item?

Tags: html, css

Assume the following list:

```
<div class="menublock">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://pornhub.com">Porn Hub</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.thestar.com">Toronto Star</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/">Example Site</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.yorku.ca">York University</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

with the following CSS

```
.menublock .menu {
margin-top: 35px;}

.menublock .menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

    .menublock .menu li a {
        font-size: 16pt;
    }
```

How do I stop the list from wrapping in the middle of a list item?
That is, I want it to line break between "Toronto Star" and "Stack Overflow" (if necessary), but not between "Stack" and "Overflow"

Line Breaks should be responsive to actual screen width, not force using child-after selectors or other such fixed points.

Comment: use `&nbsp;`? `Stack&nbsp;Overflow` would prevent the browser from splitting things there. after all, it's "(n)on-(b)reaking (sp)ace"

Comment: looks like an answer, talks like an answer...

Comment: add: `display:inline-block;` to the `a` style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `a` tag display as `inline-block`

```
.menublock .menu li a {
    font-size: 16pt;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having every list item display as "inline", have them display as "block" and have them float "left".

This will prevent breaking of text inside of each item.

I tend to make horizontal navbars this way because it eliminates issues like these as well as awkward spacing issues that result from inline elements when they are next to each other.

Edit: floating an element automatically makes it display as "block", so just eliminate "display: inline" and have your list items float left.

Comment: Good Start.  But this will allow breaking within a LI, but will do it within the block. (That is, the first row becomes 2 lines high, and the second row appears below that)  Added  white-space:nowrap; and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
.menublock .menu li a {
        font-size: 16pt;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
```